# Differences creating REST web services: symfony2 vs node.js, sails.js

Tags: php, node.js, rest, symfony, sails.js

This is not intended to be opinionated, the objective of this question is to find out the pros and cons of creating REST web services using two different technologies.

Currently I have a small team which create custom solutions usually involving a lot of integration to different systems. We want to modernise how we approach particularly the backend by creating a REST web service for each project that is consumed by web and mobile clients. We want to keep this consistent between projects as much as possible and therefore have came up with two potential solutions which play to our strengths.

The first would be using Symfony2.
The second would be using node.js with either sails.js or loopback.

I am looking for real world differences in areas like performance, unique features, scalability issues, potential limitations, anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one unmatched clear advantage for nodejs, the **performance** . nodejs uses asynchronous IO which enables non-blocking parallel operations which symfony does not do.
Another side advantage is availability of sockets but that is not needed for rest apps.

Choosing a framework is a personal choice based on framework popularity, past experience, availability of experienced programmers and availability of documentation. Im avoiding being opinionated here but all the frameworks you mentioned are pretty good at most of the things required for an API. Unless really bothered by performance, you can go for symfony if you have the expertise there and don't have the time to learn new things.